# In Git Bash for windows, how to bookmark ssh hosts

Tags: windows, ssh, git, git-bash

I sometimes use the git bash terminal that comes with the Github app for windows to ssh into my webservers. This is easily accomplished by running

```
ssh user@myhost
```

and entering the password.

In unix systems there is a usually `config` file in the `~/.ssh` directory where you can place your saved hosts and any options, such as a key file to use for password-less access.

Is there an equivalent when using Git Bash or am I forever stuck with manually constructing my ssh commands?

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is that is works in exactly the same way.

Add a `config` file within a `.ssh` folder in the home directory and populate with saved hosts.

Allowing public key access is simply a case of adding your PC's public key to the `authorized` keys file on the server you wish to log in to. The github app usually creates a key pair for you upon installation within the .ssh folder or you can create a new one using `ssh-keygen`.